# How to find the distance between characters in C with wrap-around

Tags: c, char, roulette-wheel-selection

I'm trying to find the distance between two characters in the alphabet.  However, it's OK to go from A->Z or Z->A in one step.  Given two characters, how do I find the distance?

Comment: Can the title be clarified too? (what does it mean by "pounds" anyway)

Comment: @dequis I gave it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract the two characters from each other making the result positive if it's negative.

From there, the answer is either that value, or if it's more than 13, it's 26 - value.

```
char a = '<SOME LETTER>';
char b = '<SOME LETTER>';

char distance = abs(a-b);
if (distance > 13) {
  distance = 26 - distance;
}
```